# Is there a way to have a private file constant in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have some Utils.kt file which will contain only some utility functions, no classes, no objects. And suppose that those functions use some common set of constant values.

So I do something like this:

```
package myapp

private val CONST1 = 1
private val CONST2 = 2

public fun function1() {}
public fun function2() {}
```

Unfortunately Kotlin treats **private** as "available to the whole package".
So CONST1 and CONST2 are available to all files which are in the same package.
The only way to isolate them is to move this file to a separate package.

But what if I have several utility files like this, each with its own set of *private* constants. Then i have only two options: move each of them to a unique package or give up and have consts from all of them accessible everywhere.

Either way seems to create clutter.

Any options or advice?

(**upd:** actually, I must say this is one of those rare things that bother me in Kotlin - no way to make some entity be file-local (without using some syntax hacks): it's either available to whole package or to everyone at all)

**UPD:** This question is now obsolete (see the accepted answer)

Comment: @JaysonMinard author of an accepted answer already has updated it to reflect the current state of things

Comment: Good, then I dropped the other answer since it is no longer needed.

Comment: /*kotlin programming*/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Top-level declarations with `private` visibility are visible only in the file where they are declared.

(original answer, valid when the question was asked: Kotlin does not have any concept of file-local scope, and to the best of my knowledge there are no plans to introduce it. If you don't like package scope (why?), you can create an `object` encapsulating the functions and the private constants that they use.

Comment: I do not like the package scope because I tend to have many file-local variables and they clutter all completion popups and generally I do not need them visible everywhere. I know I can use an `object`, but that seems more like a hack...

Comment: Well, in Kotlin the package structure doesn't have to correspond to the directory structure, so you can set a distinct package for every file without changing the structure of files in your project.

Comment: Yep, noticed that, just feels unusual. Is this the recommended way? Actually I feel a little beet disoriented on how to organize my Kotlin project with all this stuff in mind: default package scope, arbitrary package name per-file. And I really miss some best-practise or advice from Kotlin authors. Java is stricter here and it feels to me like this brings some order...

Comment: The recommended way is to follow the Java conventions, because it's the only way that allows you to freely mix Java and Kotlin source files within the same source root. However, for pure Kotlin projects you have more flexibility, and having a unique package per file is one of the possible approaches.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Still by following Java conventions I get into this situation which lead to the question I'm asking... Ok, I guess I'll have to learn to live with that :)

Comment: This answer is out of date, `private` is now file-local scope for top-level items.